# Can't figure out why Bison is throwing "Rules useless in parser due to conflicts"

Tags: grammar, bison, flex-lexer, bnf

I'm writing a BNF grammar for a very simple programming language and using Flex and Bison to compile.

I only have 3 variable and constant types: *real, integer, string*.

My .l file has a token definition for "ID" as follows:

```
DIGIT [0-9]
LETTER [a-zA-Z]
ID {LETTER}({LETTER}|{DIGIT})*
```

My .y file has a definition for an **identifier** like this:

```
identifier:
ID;
```

Now, I want to use the **identifier** definition to build variable and constant names. But I also want to limit assignment to data of the same type (e.g., I don't want a string assigned to an integer variable). So I created a few rules to separate each kind of variable and constant:

```
id_variable_string:
identifier;

id_variable_integer:
identifier;

id_variable_real:
identifier;
```

I did the same for constants.
Now, in my language I have a section for constant declaration/definition and then a section for variable declaration. That is, constants are declared at the same time as they're assigned (something like "myConstant = 123") but variables have to be declared first, and then assigned a value in the section specifically designed for statements.

E.g., if I want an integer and a string variable, I'd have to declare them first:

STRING myStrVariable;

INTEGER myIntVariable;

And then, in the zone reserved for statements, I can choose to do an assignment (a statement can be an assignment, a decision, a selection, an output, etc.):

```
assignment: 
        id_variable_string ASSIGN_OPERATOR literal_string
        | id_variable_string ASSIGN_OPERATOR id_const_string 
        | id_variable_string ASSIGN_OPERATOR id_variable_string 
        | id_variable_string ASSIGN_OPERATOR concatenacion  
        | id_variable_integer ASSIGN_OPERATOR id_const_integer 
        | id_variable_integer ASSIGN_OPERATOR id_variable_integer  
        | id_variable_integer ASSIGN_OPERATOR expression 
        | id_variable_integer ASSIGN_OPERATOR literal_integer
        | id_variable_real ASSIGN_OPERATOR id_variable_real
        | id_variable_real ASSIGN_OPERATOR id_const_real
        | id_variable_real ASSIGN_OPERATOR expression
        | id_variable_real ASSIGN_OPERATOR literal_real
        ;
```

What I intend here is to explicitly say that a string variable can only be assigned a string literal, a concatenation of strings (using +), a string constant or another string variable. The same for integer variables and then for real variables, only that they can't be assigned a concatenation but an expression instead (math operations).

Concatenation is defined as follows:

```
concatenation:
        id_variable_string ADD_OPERATOR id_variable_string 
        | id_variable_string ADD_OPERADOR literal_string 
        | literal_string ADD_OPERADOR id_variable_string 
        | literal_string ADD_OPERADOR literal_string
        | id_const_string ADD_OPERADOR id_const_string  
        | id_const_string ADD_OPERADOR id_variable_string 
        | id_const_string ADD_OPERADOR literal_string 
        | literal_string ADD_OPERADOR id_const_string  
        | id_variable_string ADD_OPERADOR id_const_string
        ;
```

And expression is defined as:

```
expression: 
        expression ADD_OPERATOR term
        | expression SUBST_OPERADOR term
        | term
        ;

term:
        term MULTIP_OPERATOR factor
        | term DIVISION_OPERATOR factor
        | factor
        ;

factor:     
        id_variable_integer
        | id_variable_real
        | id_const_integer
        | id_const_real
        | literal_integer
        | literal_real
        | PARENTHESIS_OPEN expression PARENTHESIS_CLOSE
        ;
```

Now, this is what Bison is saying:

55 assignment: id_variable_integer ASSIGN_OPERATOR id_const_integer

56           | id_variable_integer ASSIGN_OPERATOR id_variable_integer

58           | id_variable_integer ASSIGN_OPERATOR literal_integer

59           | id_variable_real ASSIGN_OPERATOR id_variable_real

60           | id_variable_real ASSIGN_OPERATOR id_const_real

62           | id_variable_real ASSIGN_OPERATOR literal_real

State 50 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

State 76 conflicts: 14 shift/reduce

State 130 conflicts: 2 shift/reduce

State 131 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

State 133 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

State 134 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

State 135 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

State 137 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

State 138 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

I'm assuming something in my grammar is wrong but I'm not sure what exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said:

> So I created a few rules to separate each kind of variable and constant:
>
> ```
> id_variable_string:
> identifier;
>
> id_variable_integer:
> identifier;
>
> id_variable_real:
> identifier;
> ```

And this was your problem.  There is nothing syntactically to distinguish an `id_variable_string` from an `id_variable_integer`, so you have (at least two) wasted rules.  This is what it is complaining about. It has no clue when it gets an `identifier` whether it should be treating it as an `id_variable_string` or an `id_variable_integer`.

You have to handle the type conflicts differently — a semantic check (not a syntactic check) that the type associated with the identifier is consistent with the types of the other identifiers in the expression.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan!
When you say I need to perform a semantic check, that exceeds the work done in flex and bison, right? Or there's still something I can do?

Comment: You'll have a check in the actions of the Bison code that ensures that when you have, say, `add_expr: identifier '+' identifier {…code…} ;` (not very realistic, but it serves), then the code will check that the two identifiers (`$1` and `$3` in Bison-speak) identify compatible types (both strings, both integers, both reals). 'Semantic' means 'non-grammatical' (checks performed outside the scope of the grammar). Looking at `a + b`, it is syntactically correct, even if `a` is a string and `b` is a real; it is a semantic check that ensures that it is meaningful to try to do what is requested.

Comment: Thanks again, Jonathan.
As for the grammar, I'm trying to make it work, so I removed every different "identifier" and the identifier rule and just used the token "ID" everywhere an identifier was needed.
But Bison still complains about shift/reduction in this part:
**assignment: ID ASSIGN_OPERATOR ID | ID ASSIGN_OPERATOR literal_integer | ID ASSIGN_OPERATOR literal_real**
It seems to point out some problem in my "factor" rule (I only replaced every different "identifier" with the token "ID").
I'm reading about the shift/reduce used by Bison, but I can't figure out how to fix my grammar yet :/

Comment: Since I can't see definitions of `literal_integer` and `literal_real`, it is hard to know what is up. However, since you seem to be using the standard convention of upper-case for tokens and lower-case for rules, it appears that `literal_integer` and `literal_real` are rules, and you may have a similar problem with that to what you had with your identifiers — they are not gramatically distinguishable.  You should probably fix this in the lexical analyzer; it should return LITERAL_INTEGER and LITERAL_REAL.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. I found out there was another ambiguity where ID ASSIGN_OPERATOR ID could also be formed by ID ASSIGN_OPERATOR EXPRESSION, since EXPRESSION can be reduced to form an ID.
I got to fix almost every error but one. I made a different post for that one because the explanation was a bit long: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942710/how-can-i-force-bison-to-shift-to-resolve-a-conflict. I also posted links to the whole grammar and Bison output there. If it's not too much of a trouble and you want to take a look at it, I'd be very grateful :)