# How can I force Bison to shift to resolve a conflict?

Tags: grammar, bison

I'm building this grammar for a simple programming language (already solved previous ambiguity issues: [Can't figure out why Bison is throwing "Rules useless in parser due to conflicts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918580/cant-figure-out-why-bison-is-throwing-rules-useless-in-parser-due-to-conflicts)).


This is my complete grammar: http://pastebin.com/yBHLSP0z

And this is the output file from Bison: http://pastebin.com/eAma3gWy

(sorry, they're in Spanish, but I think they're pretty self-explanatory)


The thing is, I'm still getting one shift/reduce error at state 107 (I'm translating it):

```
state 107

31 factor: ID .
48 concatenacion: ID . OPERADOR_SUMA ID
49              | ID . OPERADOR_SUMA literal_string

OPERADOR_SUMA  shift and go to state 140
OPERADOR_SUMA  [reduce using rule 31 (factor)]
$default       reduce using rule 31 (factor)
```

Now, state 107 is called from state 70:

```
estado 70

   45 asignacion: ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION . concatenacion
   46           | ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION . expresion
   47           | ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION . literal_string

    OPERADOR_RESTA   desplazar e ir al estado 55
    PARENTESIS_ABRE  desplazar e ir al estado 56
    COMILLA          desplazar e ir al estado 67
    ID               desplazar e ir al estado 107

    expresion       ir al estado 108
    termino         ir al estado 61
    factor          ir al estado 62
    concatenacion   ir al estado 109
    literal_string  ir al estado 110
    literal_real    ir al estado 63
    literal_entero  ir al estado 64
    signo           ir al estado 65
```

What I think is happening (please correct me if I'm wrong) is that when it finds a rule for "asignacion" like this:

```
asignacion: ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION concatenacion | ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION expresion
```

it sees that from "expresion" it can get an ID token (expresion > termino > factor > ID), making a **ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION ID**:

```
expresion:  
        expresion OPERADOR_SUMA termino
        | expresion OPERADOR_RESTA termino
        | termino
        ;


termino:
        termino OPERADOR_MULTIPLICACION factor
        | termino OPERADOR_DIVISION factor
        | factor
        ;


factor:     
        ID
        | literal_entero
        | literal_real
        | PARENTESIS_ABRE expresion PARENTESIS_CIERRA
        ;
```

Now, when it reaches an **ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION concatenacion** and looks at the rules for "concatenacion", it gets:

```
concatenacion:
        ID OPERADOR_SUMA ID 
        | ID OPERADOR_SUMA literal_string 
        | literal_string OPERADOR_SUMA ID 
        | literal_string OPERADOR_SUMA literal_string
        ;
```

Two of them begin with "ID". So if any of those two rules are selected, it gets to a state where it can obtain a **ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION ID**, only that with the "concatenacion" rules, it needs to find a "OPERADOR_SUMA" token afterwards. But I believe it's choking as soon as it sees that from both "concatenacion" and "expresion" can form the **ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION ID** expression.

If this is not exactly what's going on, I'd like to know what is then the problem.

And, if I'm correct as where the error happens, I really don't know how to solve it.

Please help :)


Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises from:

```
asignacion
    :   ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION concatenacion
    |   ID OPERADOR_ASIGNACION expresion
    ;
```

and the selected alternatives:

```
expresion
    :   expresion OPERADOR_SUMA termino
    ;

termino
    :   factor
    ;

factor
    :   ID
    ;

concatenacion
    :   ID OPERADOR_SUMA ID
    ;
```

Which means that when your parser encounters:

```
x = y + z
```

it cannot tell whether it is processing the first or second alternative for `asignacion`.

That's the easy part.  How to fix?  The simplest fix (if it works, which I've not tested) would be to remove the `concatenacion` rule I showed, and in the `expresion` rule, recognize when you are dealing with a `concatenacion` vs an `expresion` since they are syntactically identical:

```
ID OPERADOR_SIGNACION ID OPERADOR_SUM ID
```

You'd look at the types of the two operands of the `expresion`, and if they are both string types, then you'd assume it was a `concatenacion`, otherwise an `expresion`.

You might want to review the whole of the `concatenacion` rule, though.  You'd need to let strings through the `factor` rule, I think, so you'd add another alternative to `factor`:

```
factor
   :   literal_string
   ;
```

It would mean you'd have to reject literal strings in other rules, though, so more semantic checking.  An alternative is to introduce a separate operator other than `+` to mean 'string concatenation'.  SQL uses `||`; some languages have used `,`; you could use another token altogether, such as `@`.  There are many options once you break away from `+`.  Can you even just use 'two adjacent string expressions mean the concatenation operation', with no operator between them?

If none of that works, then get back to me.

Comment: Thanks! You're a genius! I really couldn't see the ambiguity there! I just changed the concatenation operator and it magically worked :)